# Помогите ускорить задачу на Python. Конный забег

Tags: python, numpy

ит три целых числа N, M и K — количество лошадей, количество смен позиций,

Вот мой код, делает довольно медленно, подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно изменить в алгоритме, чтобы задача решалась быстро. Можно использовать NumPy.

```
def swap(index_fg, index_sg):
    h = a[index_fg]
    a[index_fg] = a[index_sg]
    a[index_sg] = h

n, m, k = map(int, input().split())
a = [i for i in range(1,n+1)]
for _ in range(m):
    f = False
    fg, sg = map(int, input().split())
    swap(a.index(fg),a.index(sg))
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if abs(a[j] - (j + 1)) > k:
            f = True
            print('1')
            break
    if f == False:
        print('0')
```

Comment: Вложенных циклов можно избежать, если хранить список (set) лошадей, которые находятся сейчас на "интересной" позиции. Поскольку после каждой перестановки, меняются позиции только двух лошадей, то можно пере-проверять интересность только двух лошадей, а не всех.

Comment: `a.index` - тоже содержит вложенный цикл - поиск позиции по значению. Лучше хранить обратную информацию: не номер лошади, которая идет на n-й позиции, а номер позиции, на котором идет n-я лошадь.

Comment: И вообще код явно переписывали с другого языка, в питоне свап делается в одну строку и без промежуточной переменной )

Comment: @Chorkov Если проверять интересность только двух лошадей после смен позиций, то не факт, что ответ будет правильным. т.к до этого могли поменяться лошади, например 2 и 8. На след. смене интересность только двух лошадей может быть равна 0, но из-за того что до этого 8 встала на 2 позицию интересность будет равна 1

Comment: @exPriceD Именно поэтому я написал про список лошадей в интересной позиции. Нужно проверить две лошади, исправить список, вывести 1, если список непуст. Можно вместо списка хранить число лошадей в интересной позиции, но код получится чуть сложнее.

Comment: А вот смена 2 и 5 - какие лошади меняются - с номерами 2 и 5 или те, которые нынче на 2 и 5 месте?

Comment: @splash58 Меняются именно лошади с такими номерами

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не уверен, но я бы как-то так делал

```
def check(old, new, k):
    """
    Проверяем, происходит ли при замене изменение числа лошадей, поддерживающих интерес
    """
    if (abs(old) <= k) and (abs(new) > k):
        return 1
    elif (abs(old) > k) and (abs(new) <= k):
        return -1
    return 0


n, m, k = map(int, input().split())
a = [i for i in range(n)]

interes = 0

for _ in range(m):
    fg, sg = map(int, input().split())
    # для простоты кода будем работать в python'овских индексах
    fg -= 1
    sg -= 1
    interes += check(a[fg]-fg, a[sg]-fg, k)
    interes += check(a[sg]-sg, a[fg]-sg, k)
    a[fg], a[sg] = a[sg], a[fg]
    # interes - число лошадей в "интересной позиции"
    print(int(bool(interes)))
```

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо!

Comment: Отлично! Удачи!